# Top % by Group in Access

Tags: ms-access-2007, frontend

I want to preface this by saying I use the front end of access and not sql.

I have a set of data that I'm trying to do a scorecard for.  I have `Region, Store, SKU, SKU Count`.  I need to give a score of 6 to SKU's within the to 15% of their region, a score of 3 for 50-85%, and zero for anything below 50% of the region.

This is my data....I cannot figure out how to do this...am I missing a piece of data to do it?

```
R   Store   SKU SKU Cnt
24  4969    14260   -942
24  7660    14162   -54
24  78  12486   -174
24  4881    14160   -376
24  78  14161   -162
24  4905    14161   -1179
24  4901    14162   -114
24  4941    14160   -312
24  4815    17912   544
24  4926    18974   112
24  4845    14160   -160
24  4828    14162   -142
28  3004    14261   -3064
28  4813    70339   -229
28  4941    14161   -382
28  4905    12486   -161
28  4907    17912   -1150
28  4907    12486   152
28  4884    14160   -62
28  7217    14261   420
28  4845    14161   -1123
28  4853    20692   -50
28  4899    20692   40
28  4872    14261   -225
32  78  17470   993
32  4956    13978   -374
32  4948    70330   -2454
32  4815    14162   167
32  4972    14161   -242
32  4372    14261   -3613
32  5413    20692   50
32  7155    64673   60
32  78  17471   484
32  4870    20713   47
32  4926    17472   -310
32  4844    12486   -66
32  4863    17471   517
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in the front end.  Learn SQL.